# How do I prevent git clone from prompting for the user password?

Tags: git, github, repository, clone

I'm writing a Windows Powershell script to set up a new development environment. One of the steps uses `git clone` in order to pull our project from Github. I'm using the following command:

```
git clone git@github.com:Account/Project.git C:\Project
```

This works, but `git` will prompt the user for their password. Unfortunately, this line of code executes in the middle of the Powershell script, and users don't realize that it's expecting their input because everything else is automated up until this point.

I'd like to prompt the user for their password when the script first executes, but how do I pass it to `git clone`? It doesn't look like it can accept a password as one of its parameters.

Comment: github doesn't use passwords. The only reason I can think that this is happening in because their key has a password on it. Is this correct? I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Their key has a password. Our repo is private.

Comment: This discusses ssh-agent to only require keys being typed in once, but that doesn't quite do what you want does it? http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use username & password, try

```
git clone https://Account:Password@github.com/Account/Project.git C:\Project
```

if OAuth token or [personal access token (PAC)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/)

```
git clone https://anything (for example Account, OAuth or x-token-auth):Token@github.com/Account/Project.git C:\Project
```

or

```
git clone https://Token:x-oauth-basic@github.com/Account/Project.git C:\Project
```

[Git automation with OAuth tokens](https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/)